# Row Level Security, Ambiguous Reference

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I'm trying to create a policy in postgres that results in a `column reference "person_id" is ambiguous`.

To make a small, similar example let's describe 3 tables: person, group and group_member.

Person has: id, name
Group has: id, person_id and name
Group Member has: id, person_id, group_id

I've simplified my policy, but the relevant portion looks something like this:

```
CREATE POLICY insert_group_member ON public."group" FOR INSERT TO user_role WITH CHECK (
  EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM "group" AS g
      LEFT JOIN "group_member" AS gm ON
        g.person_id = gm.person_id
        AND g.id = gm.group_id
      WHERE
        g.id = id AND
        gm.person_id = person_id AND
        g.members_can_invite = TRUE
  )
);
```

person_id in this case can refer to group.person_id or group_member.person_id from the sub-select, but what I really want it to be is the person_id coming from the "with check". This generally, works in other places.

Question: is there way to clearly specify that the person_id column comes from the policy and not from the select or the join. Note: I'd have expected that aliasing the table names solves this problem, but it seems to have not.

Comment: Does `user_role.person_id` work?

Comment: @CraigRinger that changes it to - `missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_role"`

Comment: What is the definition of `user_role`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it is `CREATE ROLE user_role;`

Comment: I misread the clause, I should've said `public."group"` not `user_role`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should qualify all column references, like this:

```
...
WHERE g.id = "group".id
  AND gm.person_id = "group".person_id
```

Comment: But group_id should come from a group_member as part of the original query. I guess whatever gets passed into the policies logic.

Comment: Although this did lead me to the right answer. "group_member".person_id is the right answer. Aliasing all the other "select from" statements is the right approach, in combination with using the original table name your policy applies to. If you update your answer, I'll accept it.

For anyone else reading this, I'd recommend actually doing this in a separate function instead of an inline select. You will likely get to a place where you're getting infinite recursion. See the discussion here - http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Recursive-row-level-security-policy-td5935014.html

Comment: Actually, upon closer look I don't understand your policy at all. What are the foreign key constraints between your tables? Why do you need `group_member` in the query at all, since it is added with a left outer join and does not appear in any condition?

Comment: I changed it a bit now. I realized i made a mistake in the question (thanks). The foreign keys are between person_id => person.id for both group_member and group and group_id => group.id for group_member

Comment: But then the unqualified references to `group_id` and `person_id` should refer to `"group"`, right?

Comment: ahh yes, you're right. I see. Sorry, I got confused. Thanks!